# Particle Filter Derivation based on Forward Algorithm

Tags: monte-carlo, importance-sampling, particle-filter, sequential-monte-carlo, forward-backward

I have been studying the particle filter, sequential monte carlo methods, and sequential importance sampling.

I am interested in apply the particle filter equations to the standard forward algorithm:

$$
p(x_t | z^t) \propto p(z_t | x_t) \int p(x_t |x_{t-1}) p(x_{t-1} |z^{t-1}) dx_{t-1}
$$

Where $z^t \triangleq [z_1, z_2, ... , z_t] $

To start, what I would like to find is an empirical sampled density of $p(x_t|z^t)$

I denote the form of the sampled density (for N samples) as

$$
\hat{p}(x_t|z^t) \propto \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N w(x^{t(i)},z^t) \delta(x_t- x_t^{(i)})
$$

Where the samples of $x_t$ are denoted $x_t^{(i)}$.

To get rid of the proportion sign, we can calculate $p(z^t)$,

$$
\hat{p}(z^t) =  \int p(x_t,z^t) dx_t = \int \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N w(x^{t(i)},z^t) \delta(x_t- x_t^{(i)}) dx_t \\
=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N w(x^{t(i)},z^t)
$$

Thus, dividing by $\hat{p}(z^t)$ normalizes the importance weights in our posterior distribution. I denote the normalized weights as $\tilde{w}(x^{t(i)},z^t)$.

$$
\hat{p}(x_t|z^t) = \sum_{i=1}^N \tilde{w}(x^{t(i)},z^t) \delta(x_t- x_t^{(i)})
$$

I now substitute the sampled empitical density into the forward algorithm (at time $t-1$),

$$
\hat{p}(x_t | z^t) \propto p(z_t | x_t) \int p(x_t |x_{t-1}) \sum_{i=1}^N \tilde{w}(x^{t-1(i)},z^{t-1}) \delta(x_{t-1}- x_{t-1}^{(i)}) dx_{t-1}
$$

Rearranging terms, we have

$$
\hat{p}(x_t | z^t) \propto \sum_{i=1}^N \tilde{w}(x^{t-1(i)},z^{t-1}) p(z_t | x_t) \int p(x_t |x_{t-1}) \delta(x_{t-1}- x_{t-1}^{(i)}) dx_{t-1}
$$

Applying the integral we have

$$
\hat{p}(x_t | z^t) \propto \sum_{i=1}^N \tilde{w}(x^{t-1(i)},z^{t-1}) p(z_t | x_t) p(x_t |x_{t-1}^{(i)})
$$

Now I notice that the above formula is in terms of our observation density $p(z_t|x_t)$, and our transition density $p(x_t|x_{t-1})$, which are both distributions that we assume to know. Further, I assume that we have observed $z_t$ and know its value.

**Issue Starts Here:** In order to find $\hat{p}(x_t|z^t)$, we need to sample $x_t^{(i)} \sim p(x_t|x_{t-1}^{(i)})$. Denote the sampled density of $p(x_t|x_{t-1}^{(i)})$ as

$$
\hat{p}(x_t|x_{t-1}^{(i)}) = \sum_{i=1}^N \alpha_i \delta(x_t- x_t^{(i)})
$$

Where $\alpha_i =p(x_t^{(i)}|x_{t-1}^{(i)})$

A single sample from this density is $\hat{p}(x_t^{(i)}|x_{t-1}^{(i)}) = \alpha_i \delta(x_t - x_t^{(i)})$

Then substitute our sample back into the equation.

$$
\hat{p}(x_t | z^t) \propto \sum_{i=1}^N \tilde{w}(x^{t-1(i)},z^{t-1}) p(z_t | x_t) \alpha_i \delta(x_t - x_t^{(i)})
$$

Therefore, we have

$$
\hat{p}(x_t | z^t) \propto \sum_{i=1}^N \alpha_i \tilde{w}(x^{t-1(i)},z^{t-1}) p(z_t | x_t^{(i)}) \delta(x_t - x_t^{(i)})
$$

Comparing this to the original equation, we have a recursive relationship between the importance weights.
$$
\frac{1}{N} w(x^{t(i)},z^t) = \alpha_i \tilde{w}(x^{t-1(i)},z^{t-1}) p(z_t | x_t^{(i)})
$$

This is not completely correct, I have an extra term of $\alpha_i = p(x_t^{(i)}|x_{t-1}^{(i)})$. This should have been cancelled out.

I believe the correct weight update should be
$$
w(x^{t(i)},z^t) = \tilde{w}(x^{t-1(i)},z^{t-1}) p(z_t | x_t^{(i)})
$$

I believe the issue begins where I bolded above. If anyone can provide some insight, it would be very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I wonder when you try to estimate $\hat{p}(x_t|z^t) \propto \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N w(x^{t(i)},z^t) \delta(x_t- x_t^{(i)})$. What is the  target function that used to calculate the weight? Is $P(x_{0:t}, z_{1:t})$ or $P(x_{0:t} | z_{1:t})$ ?

Comment: @sundaycat I may be wrong but I believe at iteration zero it could be any educated guess. Some people may use uniform distributions or gaussian.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have answered my own question.
When you have a known distribution that you are sampling from like $p(x_t|x_{t-1})$, the monte carlo approximation for the distribution is

$$
p(x_t|x_{t-1}) = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N \delta(x_t- x_t^{(i)})
$$

For example, if $p(x_t | x_{t-1})$ follows a gaussian distribution, the monte carlo approximation of this distribution $\hat{p}(x_t|x_{t-1})$ will be a cluster of impulses each with amplitude $1/N$ that mostly lie in the region near the mean of the original distribution.

This makes sense, because if you want to calculate the probability, say in a region over a gaussian $P(a \le x_t \le b)$, then the monte carlo approximation is

$$
E[I(a \le x \le b)] = \int_{a}^{b}\hat{p}(x) dx \\
= \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N \int_{a}^{b}\delta(x- x^{(i)}) dx \\
$$

The integral evaluates to zero for particles $x^{(i)}$ not in the region $[a,b]$.

If we define the set of particles over the region $[a,b]$ as $X = \{x^{(i)} | \ a \le x^{(i)} \le b \}$ and index the set with $j$, the probability is

$$
= \sum_j\frac{1}{N}
$$

Thus, in regions where the particles are more densily packed, the probability will be higher, which is what we expect from the target distribution.